# Image not resizing in Android Studio's emulator

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, multi-touch, image-size

I'm using a USB connected device to run my app. In this practice app, I used an Android logo image to implement the zooming feature. When I try to change the image dimensions in the activity, it does not show the changes when the app imported into the usb device is loaded. The logo is simply zoomed to fit. But I want it to display the image with the way I see it in the Design view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR1fg.png

I forked the code from this source to implement the zooming: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/multi-touch-panning-pinch-zoom-image-view-in-android-using/
It does not have the double tap zoom in and out feature so let me know what I can add to implement that

And here is the code for my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.firstapp.Login"
android:id="@+id/activity_activity2"
android:focusable="false"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:id="@+id/botImg"
    android:src="@drawable/bot"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your java class try creating this view and then try changing the height and width parameters .inflate this view dynamically and assign parameters in the java itself dont use xml for this view .